# AWS lambda function list parameter is converted into string. How to pass list as a parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When I try to pass list as a parameter in AWS lambda, it converts into string of list. If I pass params

> {
> "code_call":"alert",
> "list_1":[30,90,120,180],
> "number":"180"    }

AWS lamda converts it into

```
"queryStringParameters":{
      "code_call":"alert",
      "list_1":"[30,90,120,180]",
      "number":"180"
   }
```

I can definitely use split function to convert it back to list.

```
list_1 = [int(i) for i in list_1.split(',')]
```

I was wondering if we can force it to be list instead of string.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: How exactly do you "pass list as a parameter in AWS lambda"? AWS CLI?

Comment: @Marcin, I pass these parameter from python. I pass it as dictionary { "code_call":"alert", "list_1":[30,90,120,180], "number":"180" } but when lambda function reads it, it reads as string instead of list

Comment: I mean, what full CLI command are you using?

Comment: Can you show the line of code that calls your Lambda function from Python?